# 2 dropdown select option iterating through same array but should not be able to select same selected value (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown

Currently I am trying to build 2 dropdown select option component that only shows columns, but the point is that it should not display the already selected value in other dropdown select option. So each value can only be selected once. So how can I fix that in the code.

[Click here to go to Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/chiholiu10/cryptomaniak?file=/src/components/Table/TableFilter/TableDropdownFilter.tsx)

Parent component

```
    return (
        <div>
            <TableDropdownFilter
                columns={columns}
                onSelect={setHiddenCol1}
            />
            <TableDropdownFilter
                columns={columns}
                onSelect={setHiddenCol2}
            />
            <Table
                columns={columns}
                data={data}
                hiddenColumnsOne={hiddenCol1}
                hiddenColumnsTwo={hiddenCol2}
            />
        </div>
    )
```

Child component

```
interface TableDropdownProps {
    columns: any;
    onSelect: any;
    firstFilter?: string;
    secondFilter?: string;
}

export const TableDropdownFilter: FC<TableDropdownProps> = ({
    columns,
    onSelect,
    firstFilter,
    secondFilter
}) => {
    const [columnShow, setColumnShow] = useState<string>("");
    const [openDropdown, setOpenDropdown] = useState(false);
    const wrapperRef = useRef(null);

    const useOutsideAlerter = (ref: any) => {
        useEffect(() => {
            const handleClickOutside = (event: MouseEvent) => {
                if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
                    setOpenDropdown(false)
                }
            }

            document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
            return () => {
                document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
            };
        }, [ref]);
    }

    useOutsideAlerter(wrapperRef)

    const dropdownFilter = (selectedColumn: string) => {
        setColumnShow(selectedColumn);
        setOpenDropdown(false);
        onSelect(selectedColumn);
    }

    const toggleDropdownOpen = () => setOpenDropdown(!openDropdown);
    console.log(firstFilter, secondFilter);
    return (
        <TableFilter>
            <TableFilterBlock ref={wrapperRef}>
                <TableFilterInput onClick={() => toggleDropdownOpen()}>
                    {columnShow.length > 0 ? columnShow : "Select"}</TableFilterInput>
                {typeof columnShow}
                <TableFilterDropdown toggleDropdown={openDropdown}>
                    {columns.slice(1).map((item: any, index: number) => (

                        <TableDropdownList key={index}>
                            <div onClick={() => dropdownFilter(item.id)}>
                                {item.id}
                            </div>
                        </TableDropdownList>
                    ))}
                </TableFilterDropdown>
            </TableFilterBlock>
        </TableFilter>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to pass a single value to filter by to the `TableDropdownFilter` component. Use the passed `filter` prop to do an inline filtering of the `columns` options.

TableDropdownFilter

```
interface TableDropdownProps {
  columns: any;
  onSelect: any;
  filter?: string; // <-- single filter by value
}

export const TableDropdownFilter: FC<TableDropdownProps> = ({
  columns,
  onSelect,
  filter // <-- destructure filter prop
}) => {
  const [columnShow, setColumnShow] = useState<string>("");
  const [openDropdown, setOpenDropdown] = useState(false);
  const wrapperRef = useRef(null);

  ...

  return (
    <TableFilter>
      <TableFilterBlock ref={wrapperRef}>
        <TableFilterInput onClick={() => toggleDropdownOpen()}>
          {columnShow.length > 0 ? columnShow : "Select"}
        </TableFilterInput>
        {typeof columnShow}
        <TableFilterDropdown toggleDropdown={openDropdown}>
          {columns
            .slice(1)
            .filter((item: any) => item.id !== filter) // <-- filter by item is
            .map((item: any, index: number) => (
              <TableDropdownList key={index}>
                <div onClick={() => dropdownFilter(item.id)}>{item.id}</div>
              </TableDropdownList>
            ))}
        </TableFilterDropdown>
      </TableFilterBlock>
    </TableFilter>
  );
};
```

TableComponent

Pass the appropriate `filter` value for the "other" select input.

```
export const TableComponent: FC<TableComponentProps> = ({ columns }) => {
  const [hiddenCol1, setHiddenCol1] = useState<string>("");
  const [hiddenCol2, setHiddenCol2] = useState<string>("");
  const data = useMemo(() => TableContent, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <TableDropdownFilter
        columns={columns}
        onSelect={setHiddenCol1}
        filter={hiddenCol2} // <-- filter by dropdown 2 value
      />
      <TableDropdownFilter
        columns={columns}
        onSelect={setHiddenCol2}
        filter={hiddenCol1} // <-- filter by dropdown 1 value
      />
      <Table
        columns={columns}
        data={data}
        hiddenColumnsOne={hiddenCol1}
        hiddenColumnsTwo={hiddenCol2}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit 2-dropdown-select-option-iterating-through-same-array-but-should-not-be-able-to]

Comment: Wow I was pretty close, but the point is that you reversed the props, which is nice tho.